# VBA Insert formula with offset in cell and loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've got hourly data. I need to have a cell that computes say the R<sup>2</sup> for days 1 and 7 between two different variables (say column A and B) and then loop this so next time it computes the R<sup>2</sup> for days 2-8 and then for days 3-9 etc etc.
I must say that the cell that has the R<sup>2</sup> formula is used in Solver to solve some code/formulas for max R<sup>2</sup>, so the cell that contains the R<sup>2</sup> needs to be a formula and not a value.. (I have been able to offset this as a value but not as a formula). Part of the current code is the following:

```
i = 0
ActiveSheet.Cells(24,13).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RSq(RangeA.offset(i,0), RangeB.offset(i,0)

i = i + 24
```

Many many thanks in advance for any helpful tips

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have named ranges `RangeA` and `RangeB`, you could use:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(24,13).Formula =  "=RSQ(RangeA,RangeB)"
```

Or, you can use relative references in R1C1 notation like so:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(24,13).Formula = "=RSQ(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
```

or, for multi-celled ranges:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(24,13).Formula = "=RSQ(RC[-2]:R[2]C[-2],RC[-1]:R[2]C[-1])"
```

Comment: You should using the [Range.FormulaR1C1 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527.aspx) for the latter two formula assignments, not the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx).

Comment: @Jeeped nice catch, although `.Formula` still works in this particular case.

Comment: But it needs to have an offset function, so that it computes the R2 of the next range in the series (i.e. 24 hours forward). Any ideas..?

Comment: You can build up the R1C1 string to reflect the offsets. Eg `R[24]C[2]....`

Comment: Can I put a variable (say i) in the R1C1 ? So that it adds 24 every time it loops?